# How to fix an element page position and dont allow to go up without hiding a div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have hide animation when scrolling to specific section.Here is the code

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        $windowH = jQuery(window).height();
        $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if($scroll >= $windowH){
            if($('#video-container').is(':visible')){
                $('#video-container').hide();
            }
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".main_right_content").offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }

        if($(document).scrollTop() >=$('.homeFirstSection').position().top) {
            $('.top_pinkbar').css('position', 'fixed');
        }else{
            if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
                $('.top_pinkbar').css('position', 'relative');
            }
        }  
        if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
            $('.top_pinkbar').css('position', 'relative');
        }
    });
```

When I scroll and reach the section from where some div must be hidden it hide and scroll to the top but it looks a bug cause when I scroll I see bottom parts and then it creted a look that things are reloaded.How I can hide something from the top part and without a scroll only fix that part and not allow to go up?Here is the [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8nh12c12/) with my structure

Comment: Just clarifying your question, you don't want to see the content that is on top of the div that you have scrolled to? Please let me know if I have understood it right. Or can you please create a jsfiddle or codepen version so that I can debug it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right.I dont want to see the top part that I want to hide when I scroll, and wanted with no need of scrollling fix that part of page and dont allow to go up.Thanks! @bozzmob

Comment: Tha issue is when am adding a scroll it created a look that items are preloading but I dont want that

Comment: " and wanted with no need of scrollling fix that part of page and dont allow to go up." Please can you clarify this line? Does it mean - After you are hiding the top part of the div, you are not able to scroll up? Please can you create a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) ? Put your code there. It will be very easy to debug.

Comment: yes after hiding I cannot go up

Comment: it it a bit difficult to create fiddle for this

Comment: Yes. I can understand. Please have a look at the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86607/discussion-between-bozzmob-and-anahit-dev).

Comment: @AnahitDEV then just provide html related to this code this may some effort to our try

Answer (score 0):

Writing a clear answer after understanding the problem from comments.

You are not able to see the div above, as you are hiding it-

```
if($('#video-container').is(':visible')){
    $('#video-container').hide();
}
```

So, to make it visible you have to display this div again. So, after scroll down event is complete i.e., after animate, show the div(I am assuming 'video-container' is the name of div you are talking about and I guess that looks what you are referring to as well)

```
$('#video-container').show();
```

Comment: Updated the code now. Check it. Make the div visible - .show();

Comment: when the I hide one section with logic what is happening with the rest contant, they moved up automatically, right? @bozzmob

Comment: Yes. When you want to go to specific position, all content move upwards.

Comment: So I want to override it, how I can do the hide in that way so will not need to scroll to that position,cause that scrolling part created look that content is preloading @bozzmob